# Stack Overflow cookies expiring after logging in another browser

Tags: support, login

I have this Firefox profile that is shared. I may use that **very same** profile in Linux or Windows.

The issue is every time I switch OSes I have to log in again to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange because it will invalidate the session cookies just because the USERAGENT/OS in the HTTP cookie header has changed.

This issue won't happen to any other site I visit, except Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange.

Can that be somehow fixed?

[image]

Comment: Why not just stop sharing the profile. You can use Firefox Sync to sync the two browsers.

Comment: This must be more than just a cookie issue: I'm logged in on my phone, a Windows machine, and a MacBook all at the same time.

Comment: @BSMP It's a sharing profile issue.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's probably working as designed - blocking a potential cookie-stealing attack.

Comment: @RobertLongson Firefox sync doesn't keep the entire browser in sync. I've tried it. It's not like Chrome where you recover everything. Plus it means sharing your data with Mozilla, which some may not feel comfortable with.

Comment: @peeebeee If it's just the user agent, then this seems unlikely. Anyone pretending to be you can easily get your user-agent and use it.

Comment: your data is encrypted, mozilla can't read it.

Comment: @trlkly "Plus it means sharing your data with Mozilla, which some may not feel comfortable with" so you are ok sharing it with Google? Wow

Comment: @peeebeee Sites stopped validating the user-agent string because of how easy it is to spoof

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's no reason not to validate it, along with other more subtle  tests.

Comment: @peeebeee Sure there is: it's more code to maintain. And at SO's scale, there may be a performance impact for doing work like that unnecessarily.

Answer (score -2):

If it is indeed the User-agent, then Firefox [has a highly rated extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/) to deal with this. However, you may find it is something else. It may be something to do with Firefox itself. I do remember some sites would log me out when I went from Windows to Linux and back on the same profile.